# Only default gateway NIC receives answer to Ping

Tags: networking, ping

Case **scenario** (*Kali Linux* v2 on RaspBerry Pi 2 B+):

```
luis@Fresoncio:~$ sudo route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         172.18.25.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth1
default         192.168.35.100  0.0.0.0         UG    101    0        0 eth2
... etc (see full table below)
```

Ethernet (RJ45 cable) cards (**NICs**):

```
luis@Fresoncio:~$ sudo ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.18.25.246  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.18.25.255
        inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fe92:feb3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:92:fe:b3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3013014  bytes 296362931 (282.6 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9910966  bytes 558782777 (532.8 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.33  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::b117:1000:39bb:f8f0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether a0:ce:c8:09:e3:ef  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 97636  bytes 7342211 (7.0 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 471  bytes 31163 (30.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.35.104  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.35.255
        inet6 fe80::805b:dfe3:8c3b:61ff  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether a0:ce:c8:09:f8:84  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 276507  bytes 18134656 (17.2 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 215  bytes 19996 (19.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 96  bytes 12362 (12.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 96  bytes 12362 (12.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
--- etc (see fulll table below)
```

As can be seen, this computer has **3 NICs**. **Pings to internet work** with all of them when specifying NIC:

```
luis@Fresoncio:~$ sudo ping -I eth0 -c 5 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 172.18.25.246 eth0: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=36.7 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=308 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=85.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=54 time=151 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=54 time=56.6 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 36.753/127.695/308.472/98.316 ms
luis@Fresoncio:~$ sudo ping -I eth1 -c 5 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 192.168.1.33 eth1: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=43.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=41.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=40.7 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=55 time=41.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=55 time=40.9 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4006ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 40.757/41.517/43.303/0.962 ms
luis@Fresoncio:~$ sudo ping -I eth2 -c 5 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 192.168.35.104 eth2: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=50.7 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=37.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=49.2 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=55 time=37.7 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=55 time=53.2 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 37.499/45.711/53.250/6.723 ms
```

And now the **failing case** scenario (*Ubuntu v16* on Laptop):

```
luis@Hipatio:~$ sudo route
Tabla de rutas IP del núcleo
Destino         Pasarela        Genmask         Indic Métric Ref    Uso Interfaz
default         Router-         0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp2s0
default         192.168.22.1    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enx3c18a00b753d
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp2s0
192.168.11.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp2s0
192.168.22.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enx3c18a00b753d
```

This time featuring **2 RJ45 cable NICs**:

```
luis@Hipatio:~$ ifconfig
enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  direcciónHW 68:f7:28:d2:a4:ce
          Direc. inet:192.168.11.119  Difus.:192.168.11.255  Másc:255.255.255.0
          Dirección inet6: fe80::6af7:28ff:fed2:a4ce/64 Alcance:Enlace
          ACTIVO DIFUSIÓN FUNCIONANDO MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:454517 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:1940326 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:1000
          Bytes RX:73243397 (73.2 MB)  TX bytes:2778755895 (2.7 GB)

enx3c18a00b753d Link encap:Ethernet  direcciónHW 3c:18:a0:0b:75:3d
          Direc. inet:192.168.22.51  Difus.:192.168.22.255  Másc:255.255.255.0
          Dirección inet6: fe80::4c9d:de01:a97a:fd42/64 Alcance:Enlace
          ACTIVO DIFUSIÓN FUNCIONANDO MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:194 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:355 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:1000
          Bytes RX:20096 (20.0 KB)  TX bytes:39265 (39.2 KB)

lo        Link encap:Bucle local
          Direc. inet:127.0.0.1  Másc:255.0.0.0
          Dirección inet6: ::1/128 Alcance:Anfitrión
          ACTIVO BUCLE FUNCIONANDO  MTU:65536  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:60 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:60 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:1
          Bytes RX:5099 (5.0 KB)  TX bytes:5099 (5.0 KB)
```

This time **failing** (no answer) when pinging from the non-default NIC:

```
luis@Hipatio:~$ ping -I enx3c18a00b753d -c 5 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 192.168.22.51 enx3c18a00b753d: 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3999ms
```

The **default one works** OK:

```
luis@Hipatio:~$ ping -I enp2s0 -c 5 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 192.168.11.119 enp2s0: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=51.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=52.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=50.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=55 time=50.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=55 time=51.0 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 50.812/51.498/52.995/0.826 ms

luis@Hipatio:~$ ping -c 5 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=57.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=51 time=57.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=51 time=57.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=51 time=57.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=51 time=57.6 ms
```

Same test **failing too** on **Ubuntu Mate v16 for RaspBerry Pi 2 B+** (4 RJ45 NICs this time): only the default one works. So I am wondering if the problem should be on Ubuntu (I am sure this ping tests worked on older Ubuntu versions, like v14). Anyway, knowing how to troubleshoot the issue for any Linux would be best for me.

What is going on here and how could I **ping from specific NIC**?

**NOTE 1**: The Kali's working distro on the first example has several VPNs working at the same time (a bit confusing to read, I would say), so I cut the `route` table. Here is the complete version (I would say there is no need for this, but... who knows?):

```
luis@Fresoncio:~$ sudo route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         172.18.25.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth1
default         192.168.35.100  0.0.0.0         UG    101    0        0 eth2
115.red-79-157- 172.18.25.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
67.red-79-157-8 172.18.25.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
187.red-81-32-1 172.18.25.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
227.red-81-32-1 172.18.25.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
82.red-81-33-18 172.18.25.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
190.red-83-44-1 172.18.25.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
152.red-83-44-2 172.18.25.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
249.red-83-44-2 172.18.25.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
10.red-83-52-23 172.18.25.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
172.red-83-52-2 172.18.25.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
206.red-83-52-2 172.18.25.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
33.244.222.87.d 172.18.25.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
32.246.222.87.d 172.18.25.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
235.248.222.87. 172.18.25.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
151.18.16.95.dy 172.18.25.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
196.48.16.95.dy 172.18.25.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
143.49.16.95.dy 172.18.25.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
189.54.16.95.dy 172.18.25.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
122.56.16.95.dy 172.18.25.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
11.81.20.95.dyn 172.18.25.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
237.204.22.95.d 172.18.25.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
177.206.22.95.d 172.18.25.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
163.red-95-123- 172.18.25.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
172.18.25.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth1
192.168.35.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2
192.168.35.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth2
192.168.210.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ppp0
192.168.211.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
```

... and here is the complete `ifconfig` :

```
luis@Fresoncio:~$ sudo ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.18.25.246  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.18.25.255
        inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fe92:feb3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:92:fe:b3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3018864  bytes 296745295 (282.9 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9911793  bytes 558868110 (532.9 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.33  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::b117:1000:39bb:f8f0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether a0:ce:c8:09:e3:ef  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 97908  bytes 7362465 (7.0 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 480  bytes 31821 (31.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.35.104  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.35.255
        inet6 fe80::805b:dfe3:8c3b:61ff  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether a0:ce:c8:09:f8:84  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 277209  bytes 18180584 (17.3 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 223  bytes 20612 (20.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 96  bytes 12362 (12.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 96  bytes 12362 (12.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ppp0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1446
        inet 192.168.210.141  netmask 255.255.255.0  destination 192.168.210.1
        ppp  txqueuelen 3  (Point-to-Point Protocol)
        RX packets 461  bytes 43679 (42.6 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 423  bytes 90174 (88.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.211.141  netmask 255.255.255.0  destination 192.168.211.141
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 14  bytes 704 (704.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**NOTE2**: A new clue. By researching, I have found that the **multirouting capability** could require the option `CONFIG_IP_MROUTE_MULTIPLE_TABLES` or `CONFIG_IP_MULTIPLE_TABLES` enabled in the **kernel**.
I am suspecting this as long as this is the output of the **failing** computer:

```
luis@Hipatio:/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-62-generic$ cat .config | grep "multiple" -i
# CONFIG_OPROFILE_EVENT_MULTIPLEX is not set
CONFIG_NEED_MULTIPLE_NODES=y
CONFIG_IP_MULTIPLE_TABLES=y
# CONFIG_IP_MROUTE_MULTIPLE_TABLES is not set
CONFIG_IPV6_MULTIPLE_TABLES=y
CONFIG_IPV6_MROUTE_MULTIPLE_TABLES=y
CONFIG_DEVPTS_MULTIPLE_INSTANCES=y
# Multiplexer I2C Chip support
```

And this one is the output of the **working** computer:

```
luis@Fresoncio:/usr/src/kernel$ cat .config | grep "multiple" -i
CONFIG_IP_MULTIPLE_TABLES=y
CONFIG_IP_MROUTE_MULTIPLE_TABLES=y
CONFIG_IPV6_MULTIPLE_TABLES=y
CONFIG_IPV6_MROUTE_MULTIPLE_TABLES=y
CONFIG_DEVPTS_MULTIPLE_INSTANCES=y
# Multiplexer I2C Chip support
```

**NOTE3**: Tested (or so I believe) method referred at *NOTE2* by modifying on `/etc/default/grub` the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash CONFIG_IP_MROUTE_MULTIPLE_TABLES=y"
```

As can be seen, now the system starts with this parameter at `yes`:

```
luis@Hipatio:~$ cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-62-generic root=UUID=66464d51-851f-4623-b5cb-1699901a4a9b ro quiet splash CONFIG_IP_MROUTE_MULTIPLE_TABLES=y vt.handoff=7
```

Sadly, with **no results**. Pings still failing.

Comment: There should be only one default route/gateway in one multihomed machine, and the rest most be translated into manual routes.

Comment: Indeed, it is working. Thanks you, @A.B . But why do you say that I won't go very far? Maybe because `ping` is just the only program that will work with a gateway different than the main one?

Comment: @A.B : Wouldn't it be proper to issue some `echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/enp2s0/rp_filter` too, in order to avoid some "race condition" that could set `enx3c18a00b753d` as the main route?

Answer (score 1):

By default the systems really uses one route for a given destination, the one you get with `ip route get 8.8.8.8`.
If it gets a packet on an interface that wouldn't be the one shown with the previous command, it will consider it to be some kind of spoofing attempt and will drop it.
It won't do this if you disable reverse path filtering:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/rp_filter
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/enx3c18a00b753d/rp_filter.
```

When possible, and it's always possible with the default route, loose mode (using value 2, while keeping 1 for enp2s0) is to be prefered.

About your comment, there's no race condition with enp2s0: the routing table doesn't change and isn't altered by those settings, so no race happens. See the [ip-sysctl.txt linux kernel Documentation](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt?h=linux-4.9.y)  for more details.

Now, for your goal, that's not what really should be done.
You have to set one route **table** per interface/provider and **source ip** (by the way, that's what is CONFIG_IP_MULTIPLE_TABLES for. Forget about CONFIG_IP_MROUTE* it's for multicast). And then use some selection logic with `ip`**`rule`** commands. More than one possibility. *Eg* by marking packets with iptables and use those mark with more routing *rules* , or as one of your examples did, setting specific routes for specific destinations, or even simpler (see at the end).

All the details there with examples:

http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html

It's a bit long to directly put a working example here, but it seems straightforward to follow (including some warnings etc.). Just note that you shouldn't have to alter rp_filter anymore in this case, because packets will always arrive by the expected interface, even if (and because) the routing selection algorithm isn't as simple like before.

Once in place (instead of their route based load-balancing example), you can do things with iptables. For example combining in the nat table the `statistic` module's `--every` to load balance on the fly every new connection to multiple SNATs (one per provider) you'd use.

Comment: Sometimes when rebooting `enx3c18a00b753d` becomes the default route. That is what I was calling "race condition" (maybe not the exact name).